# How to remove cross duplicates at query level

Tags: sql

```
from_station     to_station     distance      fare
---------------------------------------------------
delhi            banglore          250        3000
bombay           delhi             200        2000
bombay           kokatta           350        3500
delhi            bombay            200        2000
delhi            kokatta           250        3000
kokatta          delhi             250        3000
kokatta          bombay            350        3500
banglore         delhi             250        3000
```

Of above data I need the following filtered row only at query level

My required output is shown here:

```
from_station     to_station     distance      fare
--------------------------------------------------
banglore         delhi             250        3000
bombay           delhi             200        2000
bombay           kokatta           350        3500
delhi            kokatta           250        3000
```

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: What **logic** is used to get from the first set of data to the second?? Please **explain** in plain English!

Comment: here in above data set banglore to delhi and delhi to banglore two  rows are there as they have same fare and distance ,and my required data set is just only the one row of both,as banglore to delhi and delhi to banglore is same .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in standard SQL using `case`:

```
select (case when from_station < to_station then from_station else to_station end) as from_station,
       (case when from_station < to_station then to_station else from_station end) as to_station,
       max(distance) as distance, max(far) as fare
from table t
group by (case when from_station < to_station then from_station else to_station end),
         (case when from_station < to_station then to_station else from_station end);
```

Some databases offer `greatest()` and `least()` functions, which make this more readable:

```
select least(from_station, to_station) as from_station,
       greatest(from_station, to_station) as to_station,
       max(distance) as distance, max(far) as fare
from table t
group by least(from_station, to_station), greatest(from_station, to_station);
```